# Format for word displacement

Tags: spacing, formatting

I'm doing some frequency analysis on a string of cipher-text using displacement and was wondering if there was a better way to vertically compare the two.

So something along the lines of:

```
BABABAAABA
BABABAAABA
```

but having the second string be displaced by 1 character. I'm using `\indent` but that isn't doing the trick for all cases.

Comment: You could use \phantom{B}.

Comment: {B} just being an arbitrary character providing a blank(invisible) space? @UlrikeFischer

Comment: B as the first character from the line before. If all characters have the same width it doesn't matter, but if they differ I would use the correct character.

Comment: @DJ2: Are you setting the cypher text using regular font? Typically such displays are set using `verbatim`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use \phantom to displace text exactly by the amount the argument would take if printed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent 
BABABAAABA\\
\phantom{B}BABABAAABA

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if the text contains "i" or "m", this wouldn't look very well aligned, unless a monowidth font were used.